ORA-24960: the attribute OCI_ATTR_PASSWORD error when connecting to oracle-instant-client in node alpine (docker) in thickmode
Dockerfile
FROM node:20.11.1-alpine AS alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    tzdata libaio libnsl libc6-compat 
 
COPY ./src/instantclient-basiclite-linux.x64-23.4.0.24.05.zip /tmp/instantclient-basiclite.zip
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN unzip instantclient-basiclite.zip
RUN mv instantclient*/ /usr/lib/instantclient && \
    rm instantclient-basiclite.zip && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/instantclient/libclntsh.so.23.1 /usr/lib/libclntsh.so && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/instantclient/libclntshcore.so.23.1 /usr/lib/libclntshcore.so && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/instantclient/libocci.so.23.1 /usr/lib/libocci.so && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/instantclient/libociicus.so /usr/lib/libociicus.so && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/instantclient/libnnz.so /usr/lib/libnnz.so && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/libnsl.so.2 /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1 && \
    ln -s /lib/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2 && \
    ln -s /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

ENV DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL 64 
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/instantclient

WORKDIR /app

# Define the command to run the application
CMD ["node", "index.js >2 log.txt"]


index.js
const oracledb = require("oracledb");

oracledb.initOracleClient();
const connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
   user: "system",
   password: "test123",
   connectString : "localhost:1521/FREEPDB1"
});
console.log('ORACLEDB connection() END', connection);

Unable to connect to oracledb with initOracleClient(), but works OK without initOracleClient()
log.txt
ODPI [00214] 2024-10-04 03:21:55.014: module name is /app/node_modules/.pnpm/oracledb@6.6.0/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release/oracledb-6.6.0-linux-x64.node
ODPI [00214] 2024-10-04 03:21:55.014: load in dir /app/node_modules/.pnpm/oracledb@6.6.0/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release
ODPI [00214] 2024-10-04 03:21:55.014: load with name /app/node_modules/.pnpm/oracledb@6.6.0/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release/libclntsh.so
ODPI [00214] 2024-10-04 03:21:55.014: load by OS failure: Error loading shared library /app/node_modules/.pnpm/oracledb@6.6.0/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release/libclntsh.so: No such file or directory
ODPI [00214] 2024-10-04 03:21:55.014: load with OS search heuristics
ODPI [00214] 2024-10-04 03:21:55.014: load with name libclntsh.so
ODPI [00214] 2024-10-04 03:21:55.027: load by OS successful
ODPI [00214] 2024-10-04 03:21:55.027: validating loaded library
AppDataSource error [Error: ORA-24960: the attribute  OCI_ATTR_PASSWORD is greater than the maximum allowable length of 1024
Help: https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-24960/] {
  errorNum: 24960,
  offset: 0,
  code: 'ORA-24960'
}

Expecting the connection to be successful in thickmode too.
Followed the steps exactly as mentioned here: https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#enablingthick
Am i missing something here?

You really don't want to be using Alpine and hacking the config to get Oracle Client libraries "usable".  Since you're having to add a bunch of libraries, and you're in a virtualized environment, why not use a supported OS so you have some hope of business continuity and reliability?  Or at least stick to 'thin' mode.

See Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python

I was able to solve the same issue by targeting the instant client version to 21.12 instead of the latest 23.4.
Try choosing a different instant client package :
https://www.oracle.com/sg/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html
and update the  ln -s commands accordingly to 21.1

What's your DB version?  And what's the application code doing (e.g. passing to OCI or OCCI), or what Oracle driver are you using?
